# Error in finding minimum element in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the minimum and maximum element in an array of elements in perl, every thing is working fine but the minimum element is not getting printed:

```
@array1=();
$i=0;
$array1[$i]=<STDIN>;
$sum=$minimum=$maximum=$array1[$i];
while($array1[$i]!=" ")
{
    $i=$i+1;
    $array1[$i]=<STDIN>;
    $sum=$sum+$array1[$i];
    if($array1[$i]>$maximum)
    {
        $maximum=$array1[$i];
    }
    if($array1[$i]<$minimum)
    {
        $minimum=$array1[$i];
    }
    if($array1[$i]==" ")
    {
        last;
    }
}
print("Entered numbers are : ",@array1);
print("Sum of all numbers is : ",$sum);
print "\n";
print("Minimum number is : ",$minimum);
print "\n";
print("Maximum number is : ",$maximum);
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. `use strict;` will find variables you didn't declare with `my` among other errors. `use warnings;` will find the error you are asking about.

Comment: You try to process the last value read before checking that you got a value — always a bad move.  It is likely that undef compares low.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I feel it's not even worth addressing all the issues that are wrong with script until the OP adds `use strict;` and `use warnings` and fixes all the things those pragmas will report.  Just glancing, I can see he's using `==` instead of `eq`, but `warnings` would alert him of that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what occurs when you enter a space in your loop.  You assign it to $array1[$i].  You then check for min and max.  So if you have a string and do numeric comparisons, it will convert the string to a number if it can (such as "12" is 12).  If you have a string which is not a number (such as a space) then it convert to 0.

I suspect that you are typing positive number, so when you enter a space, the if condition for the minimum is true and space is placed in the minimum value.  If you put in a negative number, it will print out the negative number with your code.

If you move your check for the to see if you are finished to after you read in the item and before you do the checks, it would probably work better and you would not go through the comparisons as you don't really need to do any comparisons/assignments since you are finished and the entry is not a number.

Comment: i learnt that i must use "use strict; use warnings;" in my code and changed accordingly but now i am followed by another problem i.e. i am unable to stop my loop . i want to stop the loop if user enters a new line charater (enter) . so plz help me

Comment: @user3453803: Please post another question instead of asking new questions in comments

Comment: @Borodin : i am actually asking the answer of so called asked question and its not a new question. i didn't get answer i expected

Comment: @user3453803: You originally wrote, *"every thing is working fine but the minimum element is not getting printed"* and now you say, *"i learnt that i must use "use strict; use warnings;" in my code and changed accordingly but now ... i am unable to stop my loop"*. That means you are asking a *different question* and your code has *changed*. Please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Just move this:

```
if($array1[$i]==" ")
{
        last;
}
```

to beginning of the loop block!!

A simplified version of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @items;
my ( $sum, $max, $min );

while ( chomp( my $num = <STDIN> ) ) {
    last if ( $num eq ' ' );
    next if ( $num eq '' );

    $max ||= $num;
    $min ||= $num;
    $sum += $num;

    $max = $num if ( $num > $max );
    $min = $num if ( $num < $min );

    push( @items, $num );
}

printf( "Entered numbers are: %s \n", join( ', ', @items ) );
print( "Sum of all numbers is : ", $sum );
print "\n";
print( "Minimum number is : ", $min );
print "\n";
print( "Maximum number is : ", $max );
```

Comment: its not printing the minimum element

Comment: Yes because the space is evaluated as 0

Comment: yes its working can u please change it i.e. if i enter "ENTER" the loop must stop

Comment: Then change `next if ($num eq '' )` to `last if ( $num eq '' )` and that will stop when you just press enter.

Comment: @Glenn its not working, the system is asking the values even if i press enter

Comment: It doesn't handle zero in right way. If you enter zero first, then any next value will replace it. So `0` `100` leads to wrong minimum and `0` `-42` leads to wrong maximum.