# Perl while loop won't exit when blank line is entered

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to print the sum, maximum, and minimum values of list of numbers but I am struggling to get it working.

When I press Enter the loop should exit but the program keeps running

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @items;
my ( $sum, $max, $min );

while ( chomp( my $num = <STDIN> ) ) {
    last if ( $num eq '\n' );

    $max ||= $num;
    $min ||= $num;
    $sum += $num;

    $max = $num if ( $num > $max );
    $min = $num if ( $num < $min );

    push( @items, $num );
}

printf( "Entered numbers are: %s \n", join( ', ', @items ) );
print( "Sum of all numbers is : ", $sum );
print "\n";
print( "Minimum number is : ", $min );
print "\n";
print( "Maximum number is : ", $max )
```

Comment: Is this the same question as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707595/error-in-finding-minimum-element-in-perl)?

Comment: yes @borodin has told me to ask it as another question

Comment: @Glenn: The program is similar, but the problem in the previous question was that the minimum value wasn't being printed. This time the loop is not exiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can't use `chomp` inside a `while` condition like this

  ```
  while (chomp(my $num = <STDIN>)) { ... }
  ```

  because the `while` loop needs to terminate when the `<>` returns `undef` at end of file. So you must put the `chomp` as the first statement of the loop
- The simplest way to exit a loop like this is to check whether the input contains any non-space characters using the regular expression `/\S/`
- The check

  ```
  last if ( $num eq '\n' )
  ```

  won't work because you have used `chomp` to remove the newline from the input. Also, if you use single quotes `'\n'` is the two-character string `\` followed by `n`. You need double quotes like `"\n"` to create a newline
- When a scalar variable is first declared it has the value `undef`, so you can avoid any clumsy initialisation by testing for this and updating `$min` and `$max` unless the previous value is already defined and higher (or lower) than the new value

I would rewrite your program like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @items;
my ($sum, $max, $min);

while (my $num = <STDIN>) {
  chomp $num;
  last unless $num =~ /\S/;

  $max = $num unless defined $max and $max >= $num;
  $min = $num unless defined $min and $min <= $num;
  $sum += $num;
  push @items, $num;
}

print 'Entered numbers are: ', join(', ', @items), "\n";
print "Sum of all numbers is: $sum\n";
print "Minimum number is: $min\n";
print "Maximum number is: $max\n";
```

Comment: I'm sure there are some places where `unless` is preferred, but it's use here just makes me itch.  The following just reads a lot more logically to me:  `$max = $num if !defined $max || $num > $max;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can't `chomp` the input before. Also, `'\n'` is not the enter, you have to use double quotes `"\n"` to enable special characters.

The `while (<>)` loop is usually ended by <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

Moreover, you can find a module to do the work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ max min sum };

my @items = <>;
chomp @items;
my $max = max(@items);
my $min = min(@items);
my $sum = sum(@items);

print "Entered numbers are: @items\n";
print "Sum of all numbers is: $sum\n";
print "Minimum number is: $min\n";
print "Maximum number is: $max";
```

Comment: I believe the OP's intention in writing this program is to practice basic Perl, so using `List::Util` defeats the point. However the resolution of the endless looping problem is spot on. +1